# Implement HTML5 / CSS calendar

Tags: css, html, mobile, calendar

Hey I just found calendars for my app I want to develop.
Because I'm totally new to this I need some help on how I can implement that calendar into my application.

https://designsmaz.com/free-html5-css3-calendar/

Right now I just copied the css files and so on in the project folder but right now nothing shows up. So I think I got to implement something in my app or place that stuff in an other directory.
For developing I'm using Intel XDK.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just added the index file from the online project to my project directory and it works fine. So I'm able to go on testing. ;)